# brew install sklearn didn't work. What to do next?

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, sklearn-pandas, quandl

Heyyy, so I'm following [a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcI5Vnw0b2c) that requires me to install **sklearn**, **quandl**, and **pandas**.

Unfortunately the video author is using Windows and gave no explanation of what to do if on a Mac. I thought maybe I could use homebrew, so I installed homebrew and tried **brew install sklearn**, but that didn't work.

```
Error: No available formula with the name "sklearn"
```

When I tried **pip install sklearn** I got

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I had read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x#18947390) by user acidjunk: *"a home brew python already has pip."* I didn't understand this the first time I read it. Now I understand that pip is included in *some* Python installations. But I've also since learned that installing that way can result in a double installation of Python, so I'm hesitant about doing that.

Also, the accepted answer for that question about installing pip uses sudo, and a comment was made *"Never sudo install a package for any language. This is insecure and will ruin your life later as more and more packages need sudo permissions."* which sounds like a reasonable argument, and that's why I haven't installed pip that way.

Another user [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457225/install-custom-sklearn) elsewhere on Stack Overflow *"I can use install sklearn using pip or home brew"*, so there must be some piece of the puzzle I'm missing if it worked for them but not for me.

To further complicate matters, another user suggested **brew install pip**, but when I tried that I got the following message:

```
Homebrew provides pip via: `brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can install
pip via the instructions at:
  https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/
```

Of course I followed [the link](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/), but on the page it says: *pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 binaries downloaded from python.org, but you'll need to upgrade pip.*

I have Python 2.7.10 installed, but I didn't get it directly from python.org. I want to make sure that I install it in a way that it will be compatible with homebrew and the packages I mentioned. And I don't think I want to end up with two Pythons installed (unless I need to).

Also, the tutorial author is using Python 3.5.x, so I guess I need to get both 2.7.10 and 3.5.x installed... in a way that they play nicely together. But in any case I don't want to end up with two instances of 2.7.10 in different locations or anything like that.

What's the best way to proceed? Any help greatly appreciated.

---

### Revisiting in 2023 May:

This question specifically never really got resolved, despite [Slam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2161778/slam)'s helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48464620/2454914). Since the question somehow now has 2K views, I think it's worth mentioning what the main problem was. When I posted this question years ago, I didn't know about Python **version management** or **virtual environments**, and I don't think using them was as common practice as it is today.

I still don't use Python *a lot*, but when I do, I use the version management tool `pyenv`. Here are links to a few good articles that explain it: [1](https://towardsdatascience.com/managing-virtual-environment-with-pyenv-ae6f3fb835f8), [2](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/), [3](https://opensource.com/article/19/6/python-virtual-environments-mac).

Going hand-in-hand with version management is environment management. I myself am still learning, but for anyone who is as confused as I was when I posted my question, this helpful guide may be the best place to start: [What is the difference between venv, pyvenv, pyenv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pipenv, etc?](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/python/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrapper-pipenv-etc.html) Every Python beginner course ought to teach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know, `sklearn` alias is deprecated. You may give a try with `brew install scikit-learn`
2. For some reason, you don't have `pip` as system command. This is probably because you're using system-bundled python. Apple is famous for bundling super-old system deps. I propose to install proper python version with `brew`. It should install python *and* pip. Or use official [installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-364/)
3. Even with current installation, you probably should be able to run pip as module with

   ```
   python -m pip install -U pip
   ```

Comment: I did **brew install python** and it appears to have gone through the installation steps, but when I type **python --version** it shows 2.7.10... did it install *another* instance of 2.7.10? Why didn't it install the current 3.6.4? And does this mean I need to uninstall it now and start over?

Comment: This is complicated )
I think, in OSX/brew, python2 is default version for system utils. Thats why `python` can not be linked to python 3, even if its available in system. To install 3.6 `brew install python3` should work. To run it you should try `python3` or `python3.6`.

Comment: Even though I never achieved what I was trying to, I realize now that my issue was part of a bigger problem of not knowing how to manage multiple Python environments. So I have expanded about this a little in my original question (see the "Revisiting..." section), and I have finally accepted your answer. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: This is one of the most awesome surprising comments I've ever read ) I'm happy that you've improved your overall understanding on deps management and reflected on this. This is great